# What permutations are the elements of a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

As part of an exercise, I’m to find a non cyclic abélien group of permutations with $n^2$ elements for every natural number $n$ >3.
I’m pretty sure that $(1,2,...n)$x$(n+1,n+2,...2n)$ fulfils this.

However, I now need to find all the elements of this group for $n=4$ $n=10$. 
Are these just $((1,2,3,4)(5,6,7,8))$ and $((1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20))$ or are there other elements in these groups?

Comment: I don't understand your notation. I think you want to say, for example for $n=4$, the group generated by $(1\ 2\ 3\ 4)$ and $(5\ 6\ 7\ 8)$, and that is indeed non-cyclic, abelian, with $4^2$ elements.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson . Yes that’s what I mean. What would the elements in that group be?

Comment: If x and y commute, and each has order 4, then what are the elements of the group they generate?

Comment: Yep I’m guessing the elements are all different permutations?

Comment: Well, all of the elements are permutations, and all of the elements are different, but the elements don't include all possible permutations, if that's what you mean. $(1\ 2\ 3)$ isn't an element, neither is $(1\ 2\ 4\ 3)$, nor $(1\ 2\ 3\ 5)$.

Comment: I’m confused as to how to work out what they are then. Are you able to list them or are there too many?

Comment: Each cyclic group of permutations or order $n$ is generated by a generator, for example, $(1\ 2\ 3\ 4)$. In your case, for the product group you have another generator, for example, $(5\ 6\ 7\ 8)$. They together generate $n\cdot n=n^2$ group elements by taking the product of different pairs of group elements.

Comment: But you know how many there are, 111abelian – you know there are 16. In my $x,y$ notation, they are the elements of the form $x^ry^s$ with $0\le r\le3$ and $0\le s\le3$.